# How to join values of map in python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a map like:

```
0,15
1,14
2,0
3,1
4,12
5,6
6,4
7,2
8,8
9,13
10,3
11,7
12,9
13,10
14,11
15,5
```

To print that I am doing

```
def PrintValuesArray(su_array):
    for each in su_array:
        print ",".join(map(str, each))
```

However I only want the values and comma separated like:

I have tried

```
def PrintSuffixArray(su_array):
    for key, value in su_array:
        print ",".join(map(str, value))
```

but got

> print ",".join(map(str, value)) TypeError: argument 2 to map() must
>   support iteration

and also

```
def PrintSuffixArray(su_array):
    for key, value in su_array:
        print ",".join(map(str, value in su_array))
```

> print ",".join(map(str, value in su_array)) TypeError: argument 2 to
>   map() must support iteration

How to print result like

```
15, 14, 0, 1, 12, 6, 4, 2, 8, 13, 3, 7, 9, 10, 11, 5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, iterate through the list and get only the second element (you can use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for shorthand). Then use `",".join(list)` to get the desired output, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join:

```
>>> original = """0,15
... 1,14
... 2,0
... 3,1
... 4,12
... 5,6
... 6,4
... 7,2
... 8,8
... 9,13
... 10,3
... 11,7
... 12,9
... 13,10
... 14,11
... 15,5"""
>>> 
>>> print [i.split(",")[1] for i in original.split("\n")]
['15', '14', '0', '1', '12', '6', '4', '2', '8', '13', '3', '7', '9', '10', '11', '5']
>>> print ",".join([i.split(",")[1] for i in original.split("\n")])
15,14,0,1,12,6,4,2,8,13,3,7,9,10,11,5
```

or if you have them in tuples:

```
>>> original = """0,15
... 1,14
... 2,0
... 3,1
... 4,12
... 5,6
... 6,4
... 7,2
... 8,8
... 9,13
... 10,3
... 11,7
... 12,9
... 13,10
... 14,11
... 15,5"""
>>>
>>> original_tuples = [tuple(i.split(",")) for i in original.split("\n")]
>>> original_tuples
[('0', '15'), ('1', '14'), ('2', '0'), ('3', '1'), ('4', '12'), ('5', '6'), ('6', '4'), ('7', '2'), ('8', '8'), ('9', '13'), ('10', '3'), ('11', '7'), ('12', '9'), ('13', '10'), ('14', '11'), ('15', '5')]
>>> ",".join(map(str,[j for i,j in original_tuples]))
'15,14,0,1,12,6,4,2,8,13,3,7,9,10,11,5'
```

Alternatively, you can skip the `map(str,list)` and cast the elements into string within the list comprehension

```
>>> ",".join(str(j) for i,j in original_tuples)
'15,14,0,1,12,6,4,2,8,13,3,7,9,10,11,5'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
print ", ".join(str(y) for x, y in su_array)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `str.join()` with a list-comprehension:

```
>>> su_array = [(0, 15), (1, 14), (2, 0), (3, 1), (4, 12), (5, 6), (6, 4), (7, 2), (8, 8), (9, 13), (10, 3), (11, 7), (12, 9), (13, 10), (14, 11), (15, 5)]
>>> ', '.join([str(b) for _, b in su_array])
'15, 14, 0, 1, 12, 6, 4, 2, 8, 13, 3, 7, 9, 10, 11, 5'
```

Comment: Since you aren't using `a` in your example, you can actually replace it with an underscore `-`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = """0,15
... 1,14
... 2,0
... 3,1
... 4,12
... 5,6
... 6,4
... 7,2
... 8,8
... 9,13
... 10,3
... 11,7
... 12,9
... 13,10
... 14,11
... 15,5
... """
>>> map(lambda x: x.split(',')[1], a.split())
['15', '14', '0', '1', '12', '6', '4', '2', '8', '13', '3', '7', '9', '10', '11', '5']
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, from your question, based on the output you mention, you have something like

```
`su_array = [(1, 14), (2, 0), (3, 1), ...]` etc...
```

Based on that, using either:

```
print(", ".join(str(a[1]) for a in su_array))
```

Or

```
print(", ".join(map(lambda a: str(a[1]), su_array)))
```

Are both ways to get you what you want.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @moken I added to my answer, to clarify it more.